# Calling different scripts depending on the date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to run different scripts depending on what date it is, but im not 100% sure on how to go about it, basically what I am trying to do is :
A cron script runs every day and calls a php file on the server, in the php file I need to put something like :

run everyday.php every day

run everymonday.php every Monday

run firstmondayofthemonth.php on the first Monday of each month

so I need to check when the date is equal to each of the 3 and run that script then, but im not sure what command in php is best for this ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have to do it with php (alternative would be to just create 3 cronjobs and configure cron) then this might give you an idea:

```
$weekday = date('D');
$dayOfMonth = date('d');
run everyday.php;
if ($weekday == 'Mon')
{
  run everymonday.php
  if ($dayOfMonth <=7)
    run firstmondayofthemonth.php;
}
```

You need to adapt the code of course, for example replacing the run-thing by something that suits your environment. Could be include, execute or an http request,...

Comment: how do I call another script where you have put run every monday ?, do you just echo the url / name of the script ?

Comment: That depends on: Do you know the content of the script (or can you at least make some assumptions?), is the target script on the local server and do you have privileges to access the file directly and upon limits of your environment (can you call exec(), do you run in safe-mode,...). I suggest you make this a seperate question.

Comment: @IainSimpson: Be aware that I changed dayOfMonth<=6 to dayOfMonth<=7. Just occured to me after thinking about it for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply putting this into the [cron](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) itself since you can specify which days of the week certain scripts run on but if you want to do it in php then use the [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) maybe with option 'D' to check what day it is and have a switch case statement.

For example:

```
0 0 * * 1 php runatmidnightonmonday.php
0 0 * * 6 php runatmidnightonsaturday.php
0 0 * * 0 php runatmidnightonsunday.php
```

Comment: Different people want to receive prices at different times, so each of the php files only runs the clients that have the option ticked in their profile, that's why im doing it with php instead of cron.